# use a C library in xcode for macOS

Tags: c, xcode

although I have some knowledge with XCode, Swift, I never used an external C library, so please do not be too rude with my question.

I need to use the following library: https://github.com/fbx/foils_hid (which uses two other libraries which are in the subprojects folder (https://github.com/fbx/libela and https://github.com/fbx/librudp)

I'd like to use the whole foils_hid library in Xcode to build a Macos/iOS app but I do not understand how to include those library in Xcode or if I have to compile them before (and in this case, how to compile them - I tried with shell without success)

I read that it might be possible to include the foils_hid library as a swift package but I also did not get so far. Is this possible? Do I have to compile each part with Makefiles or Xcode? Ideally a Swift package would be perfect (is there an how to guide to learn how to do it?)

Any hint on the best approach would be really appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

P

Comment: You will have to compile the projects on your Mac before you can use them. Unless someone builds a swift package, you cannot access the code that way. Once you have compiled them, you could make a swift package for future users. You can try building the projects in Xcode or from the command line. To use Xcode, import the files into a new project. Set the project type to "command line" and set the language to C.

Comment: Thanks John. I tried this already but faced issues with paths. Libraries are nested (rudp and ela) so can't be built separately.

Comment: you'll have to build the dependent libraries first.